# write to status file fast

Tags: python, file-io

My Python script needs to write status to a text file several times a second, overriding the previous content.

```
fp = open('status.txt', 'w')
fp.write('12983214/23180100')
fp.close()
```

How would you recommend implementing this to minimize time spent here? Command line call? Separate thread?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're writing out a progress number. That means your string will never get shorter, only longer.

Because of that, you don't have to truncate it before each write -- just seek back to the beginning and write over the previous value. Follow that up with a flush so that the data will be available to whatever is monitoring the status.

Doing this several times a second shouldn't take any significant amount of time, and it's the simplest solution.

```
fp = open('status.txt', 'w')

#whenever you want to write
fp.seek(0)
fp.write('12983214/23180100')
fp.flush()

#when you're done
fp.close()
```

If the status string can get shorter, just add

```
fp.truncate(0)
```

before the `write`. You still need to `seek` as well because truncating doesn't change the current file position.

All of these methods are documented under [built-in file objects](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

Comment: this is a monitor and is probably best in its own thread, that doesn't take away from the answer given however.

Comment: Perhaps even http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=flush#file.flush ?

Answer (score 1):

"write status to a text file several times a second"
I think you can save the file instance until wouldn't to write to it. Now to close file instance. Before close you can write many times.
open and close usually is costs some efficiency.

"overriding the previous content"
if you override the previous content why not write a final result in the end time?

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what you're trying to say. Could you try and make it more clear? He needs to write new values because something is reading the file repeatedly to track status information -- it's not the end value that matters.

Comment: @agf: their point is pretty clear: do not use files for what they are not for.

Comment: @thg435 On Unix / Linux, everything is a file. There are entire "filesystems" devoted to communicating information like this -- procfs, sysfs, etc. This is a perfectly valid way to use a file.